# npm start: Manual browser refresh to reflect changes

Tags: html, node.js, npm, node-modules, page-refresh

I'm learning Node.js and in the introductory course, I had to set-up node and npm. Now according to the instructor, after typing "npm start" in the terminal and then making changes in the index.html file, the browser is supposed to automatically refresh the tab for the changes to take effect, but in my case every time I make a change I had to manually refresh Safari tab to see the changes.

Please note I'm using the same machine, i.e. there is no server and client side per se. Operating system is macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

Any possible fixes please?

Thanks

**File Structure:**
[image]

**package.json file:**

```
  {
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a website for Ristorante Con Fusion",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "author": "Raffay",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/RaffaySajjad/conFusion.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "conFusion"
  ],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/RaffaySajjad/conFusion/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/RaffaySajjad/conFusion#readme"
}
```

**Starting nodemon from terminal using command "nodemon" prints following error**

```
raffaysajjad@192 ~ % cd /Users/raffaysajjad/Desktop/Full\ Stack\ Web\ Development\ \(React\ Specialization\)/Course\ 1\ \(Front-End\ WebUI\ Frameworks\ \&\ Tools\ -\ Bootstrap\ 4\)/Week\ 1/Exercise/conFusion
raffaysajjad@192 conFusion % nodemon
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: html,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.html`
/Users/raffaysajjad/Desktop/Full Stack Web Development (React Specialization)/Course 1 (Front-End WebUI Frameworks & Tools - Bootstrap 4)/Week 1/Exercise/conFusion/index.html:1
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: i suggest you to use nodemon for this.

Comment: If you use Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-server-web-extension/fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj/

Comment: Though, I think this might just be for when you use a template engine. If you're just using Node server-side, you could (as others have said) use nodemon along with with something like VSCode Live Server: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer should work but not 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is done by using the npm package of nodemon,

**How to Use**

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

and in your package.json use this

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon npm run lite"
  },
```

more about nodemon [learn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) here

Comment: So I installed nodemon but I'm not sure what file to choose in place of "my_file.js" in scri[ts. I just have html file with me. Can you please have a look at my file structure I attached and let me know?

Comment: Can you please let me know how I should start it. I don't have a js file to point to. I used to start my server using "npm start" previously but it is crashing now. Thanks!

Comment: If you have it installed globally you can just type `nodemon` in the CLI and it will look for the `main` file specified in your package.json: "If you have a package.json file for your app, you can omit the main script entirely and nodemon will read the package.json for the main property and use that value as the app."

Comment: Thanks. After reading the documentation and your explanation, I inferred that after navigation to the folder where I installed nodemon, I need to type nodemon in the terminal and it should open up the default page. This is what I did but the nodemon says app crashed. I had attached the terminal output. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Are you actually using Express/Node.js as a backend? I don't see any JS files in your directory

Comment: If you only have HTML files you can use VSCodes [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension, assuming you use VSCode?

Comment: Well the course is about Node.js and instructor specifically mentioned to install Node.js. I think those files will be added later. For now I'm working on html pages which should be refreshed when the file is changed. For the time being I installed live-serve in VSCode. It is working as expected. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe Nodemon is relevant, Nodemon's purpose is "automatically restarting the node application when file changes in the directory are detected" see also "nodemon was originally written to restart hanging processes such as web servers". It does not refresh the browser.

Comment: @edwinbradford if you do live server, nodemon will refresh the browser.

Comment: @CodeBug Are you referring to VS Code Live Server https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.Try installing nodemon.

```
npm install nodemon
```

It is a tool that helps develop node.js based applications by automatically restarting the node application when file changes in the directory are detected.
To run your server :

`nodemon [your node app]`

Comment: I installed nodemon but I'm not sure what is my "node app name". Can you please have a look at my File Structure and let me know? Thanks

Comment: What's your inject javascipt main file?.You can check this in the package.json->main

Comment: I couldn't find a javascript file in my package.json. Can you please have a look? I attached it in my question. Probable I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Nodemon will not helo you to browser reload for that kind of things you jest try plugins like [connect-livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-livereload)

There are so many packages are there for this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload

https://www.browsersync.io/

Comment: I have a look at connect-reload. In the documentation it states that, to use it, I should place some code in my html file and there is also express.js. I have an HTML file but not sure where I can find the .js file. Can you help please?